# React Native iOS is saving fetched data until I uninstall the app?

Tags: ios, xcode, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to figure out what is causing this issue. When I open the app, I go to the first screen. The screen contains data that is fetching from json data. Then when I switch to another screen and back to the first screen the same data is still there. I'll explain why it should be different. **I am fetching data from mysql database using a random query (RAND())** It should be different every time I go back to the first screen.

When I uninstall and reinstall the app, I see the newly fetched data, but the problem still proceeds if I repeat the steps.

This works on Android, but not on iOS:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (!prevState.user_image) {

    fetch('https://www.exmaple.com/React/user.php')
     .then((response) => response.json())
     .then((responseJson) => {
       this.setState({
         isLoading: false,
         user_image:  responseJson

         }, function() {
           const {userLikes, user_image} =  this.state;
           this.setState({
               combinedArray: userLikes.map(likes => Object.assign(likes, user_image.find(images => images.id == likes.id)))
           });


       });
     })
     .catch((error) => {
       //console.error(error);
     });

  }
}
```

I don't know if Xcode have some kind of fetch data caching. Basically what is happening is (In web development terms) CSS caching, but with fetched data. If that makes sense.

Also I am using a `react-native-react-navigation` Tab Navigation...maybe that's the problem and it's saving fetched data?

Comment: perhaps the second time the output of !prevState.user_image is not null/defined/false?  Check the output of that first conditional to see if the fetch call is even getting called. You can also see if componentDidUpdate is getting called again.

You might want to move this code to componentDidMount and remove the first conditional statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was right! It was because the fetch is caching. I had to insert no caching headers in the fetch.